# Apex: sorting combined lists to get earliest date

Tags: apex, soql

I've got two lists of leads I'm combining into one like so:

```
List<Lead> leads = new List<lead>();
leads.addAll(query1Leads);
leads.addAll(query2Leads);
```

How can I sort `leads` by a custom field like `Lead_Generation_Date__c` to get the earliest date in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one simple way to sorting based on field value.. (**use order by**)

Query all the record based on id and use order by In your query

```
List<Lead> leads = new List<lead>();
leads.addAll(query1Leads);
leads.addAll(query2Leads);

List<Lead> leads1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM lead WHERE Id IN: leads ORDER BY Lead_Generation_Date__c ];
```

If you dont want to use query then you need to compare each object's field and then sort based on that...

---

**Edit**

Or **use Comparable Interface**

Reference:-  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm

[Custom Sort Order of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

**Example..**

```
global class OpportunityWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Opportunity oppy;

    // Constructor
    public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity op) {
        oppy = op;
    }

    // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Cast argument to OpportunityWrapper
        OpportunityWrapper compareToOppy = (OpportunityWrapper)compareTo;

        // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (oppy.Amount > compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (oppy.Amount < compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }
}
```

Test the above code

```
OpportunityWrapper[] oppyList = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        Date closeDate = Date.today().addDays(10);
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Edge Installation',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=50000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='United Oil Installations',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Needs Analysis',
            Amount=100000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Grand Hotels SLA',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=25000)));

        // Sort the wrapper objects using the implementation of the 
        // compareTo method.
        oppyList.sort();
```

This will sort the list based on `opportunity Amount field`

Comment: Waiting for the time limit is all. :)

Comment: This is not at all a good way to do this. I would recommend to implement this using wrapper class and comparable interface.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty I suggest please add an ans to this question with comparable interface.. So for future reference it will be helpful for others.